# How to solve this problem using spherical coordinates system?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, spherical-coordinates

The question is very simple:

Volume inside the solid limited by:$ (X^2+Y^2+Z^2=16), (X^2+Y^2=4)$

using SPHERICAL coordinates system.

The final answer however can be checked making a "cylindrical integration".

Comment: The answer is simply the volume of a sphere with radius 4

Comment: Actually the solid is a regular cylinder with a "piece" of sphere at the top (graph the functions if this is confused). Anyway, the answer for this question is 46.97 for each cylinder. (We have 2: one in the positive "Z" axis, and another cylinder in the negative "Z" axis).

The problem is not how to resolve it... is how to resolve using spherical coordinates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
In general, when you integrate a volume that includes the origin, $\theta $ and $\phi $ are integrated between 0and $\pi$ and 0 and $2\pi$, respectively. If the volume is convex (or, more generally, star-shaped as it is called) then the shape is determined by the surface function $r(\theta,\phi)$. For example, in the case of a sphere of radius 4 it is $r(\theta,\phi)=4$, in the case of an spheroid is, for example, $r(\theta,\phi)=(1+0.5\cos\theta)$, in the case of a cube is very complicated, so dont use spherical coordinated to calculate the volume of a cube, but in principle there is no problem.

In this case, as you point out, the volume is a cylinder with height 4 and sphere pieces on the top and bottom. N the direction of these pieces,the surface is just the sphere, and in the other directions the surface of the cylinder fullfils $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/r(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta$. The equations below just summarizes all this

$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{r(\theta)}r^2 d r$
where 
$r(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
4 & \theta<\pi/6~{\rm or}~\theta>5\pi/6\\
2/\sin\theta & \neg
\end{cases}$

We can integrate in the following way

$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{r(\theta)}r^2 d r\\ &= \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \frac{r(\theta)^3}{3}\\
&= 2\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \frac{r(\theta)^3}{3}\\
&=2\pi\left(\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{r(\theta)^3}{3} \sin\theta d\theta +\int_{5\pi/6}^{\pi}\frac{r(\theta)^3}{3} \sin\theta d\theta +
\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\frac{r(\theta)^3}{3} \sin\theta d\theta\right)\\
&=2\pi\left(\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{64}{3} \sin\theta d\theta +\int_{5pi/6}^{\pi}\frac{64}{3} \sin\theta d\theta +
\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\frac{8}{3\sin^3\theta} \sin\theta d\theta\right)\\
&=2\pi \left(64\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})}{3}+\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\frac{8\csc^2\theta}{3} d\theta\right)\\
&=2\pi \left(64\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})}{3}+\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}} \right)\\
&\sim 93.96
\end{align}
$
Note that the integrals are symmetric respecto to $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you get this?

Comment: When I read your answer, I found the following:
$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\theta d\theta \int_{2/sin\theta}^{4}2r^2 d r$

..I mean, I put a "2" in the integrand and I changed the lower limit for de Last Integral... Is That Correct?

Because, doing what I said, you get a Volume of 93.9, wich is the correct answer...

Comment: I don't know about your integral. Note that there, sometimes $2/sin(\theta)>4$, so the integral would be negative. I also get 93.9578  when integrating the expression I give in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got your point, what you said made sense so I believe that your integral is absolutely correct, but I'm having problem to evaluate it... It is a very elementar problem, so really really sorry, but can you put the steps to evaluate your expression?